# Не могу импортировать модуль

Tags: python

Есть основной скрипт, в который импортируется мой модуль:

```
from lib import isCloudFlare
```

Но для работы этого модуля нужен модуль **netaddr**. Я его загрузил, распаковал из архива и поместил папку netaddr в папке lib так, что папка соседствует с моим модулем. В самом модуле isCloudFlare я сделал импорт netaddr:

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork, IPAddress
```

Но почему-то я получаю ошибку **no module named 'netaddr'**, если пытаюсь запустить основной скрипт. А если запустить только сам модуль isCloudFlare, то импорт проходит нормально. Почему так происходит и что нужно сделать, чтобы это исправить?

Comment: `загрузил, распаковал из архива и поместил папку netaddr в папке lib` – а чем вам не подошла установка через `pip install netaddr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пути для импортирования модуля считаются [абсолютно](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/). Попробуйте `from lib.netaddr import IPNetwork, IPAddress` должно сработать.